# How to get XML elements with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need help selecting from an XML string.

With some help a few minutes ago, I managed to parse an XML input
with this code.

```
foreach (XElement element in xml.Descendants("{" + ns + "}VehicleValue").Elements())
{
        Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
};
```

(where ns is the namespace.)

Now I want to select it into a bunch of variables (properties)
    with this

```
var r = xml
    .Descendants("{" + ns + "}VehicleValue").Elements()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        #region all the Nodes/Fields

        AdjustedEstimatedCostPrice = x.Element("AdjustedEstimatedCostPrice").Value,
        AdjustedEstimatedCostPrice_MileageAndCondition = x.Element("AdjustedEstimatedCostPrice_MileageAndCondition").Value,
     });
```

but it doesn't select or populate my variables.
I'd have thought that if the foreach works and I applied the same instruction to the select it would work?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
   -<s:Body>
      -<GetConvergedDataRequestResponse xmlns="http://autoinsight.trann.co.za/types" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

          -<ConvergedData i:type="ConvergedResults" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Trann.Auto.Convergence.B2B.BusinessModels">
               <AccidentHistory i:nil="true"/>
               <AlertInfo i:nil="true"/> 
               <CloneInfo i:nil="true"/>
               -<DiskDriveInfo>
                    <ResultCode i:nil="true"/>
                    <ResultCodeDescription i:nil="true"/>
                    <AirbagDetails>DRIVER, PASSENGER</AirbagDetails>
                    <Alarm>NO</Alarm>
                </DiskDriveInfo>
                <EnquiryHistory i:nil="true"/>
                <FactoryFittedExtras i:nil="true"/>
                <Finance i:nil="true"/>
                <MileageHistory i:nil="true"/>
                -<VehicleCodeAndDescription>
                    <ResultCode i:nil="true"/>
                    <ResultCodeDescription i:nil="true"/>
                    <VehicleCode>60007400</VehicleCode>
                </VehicleCodeAndDescription>
                <VehicleConfirmationInfo i:nil="true"/>
               -<VehicleValueInfo>
                   -<VehicleValue>
                        <ResultCode i:nil="true"/>
                        <ResultCodeDescription i:nil="true"/>
                        <AdjustCostPrice>0</AdjustCostPrice>
                        <AdjEstCostPrice>0</AdjEstCostPrice>
                        <CostPrice>0</CostPrice>
                        <TradePrice>0</TradePrice>
                        <VehicleCode>60007400</VehicleCode>
                   </VehicleValue>
              </VehicleValueInfo>
              <VesaInfo i:nil="true"/>
         </ConvergedData>

         <ResponseStatus xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" i:nil="true"/>

      </GetConvergedDataRequestResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: First you need to show what your XML looks like or we can't help. We need a [mcve]

Comment: How did you conclude that it does not `Select` or Populate? My guess is try doing a `.ToList()` after your `Select.`

Comment: I checked the Properties..all null

Comment: What is the `Count()` of `r`?

Comment: Could you please update the question with the child elements of `VehicleValue`?

Comment: I've  added the xml from a previous question answered by Sebastian

Comment: Thanks for the update. It seems you are trying to select the wrong elements; for example: there isn't an element with the name `AdjEstCostPrice_MileageAndCondition`...

Comment: `x.Element("AdjustedEstCostPrice").` should use a namespace too: `x.Element(ns + "AdjustedEstCostPrice").`

Comment: That unfortunately was my editing. Finding the lengths of these element names etc really long and cumbersome.

Comment: I've amended it now. thx

Comment: Tried adding the namespace in as suggested..but still nada

Comment: Checked the Count, which is zero.

Comment: From what I can see is that your xml is a soap response. You should rather use serialization to convert it into a c# class..

Comment: It is a SOAP response yes.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the VehicleValue element? When I try your code, I don't get the element...

Comment: My foreach is writing each element to the Console.
eg. 
<VehicleCode xmlns="http://autoit.trann.co.za/types">60007400</VehicleCode>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code. First you are selecting `.Elements` after you get the descendants. Also you are missing namespaces. Try this code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://autoinsight.trann.co.za/types";

var result = doc
    .Descendants(ns + "VehicleValue")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AdjustCostPrice = x.Element(ns + "AdjustCostPrice").Value,
        AdjEstCostPrice = x.Element(ns + "AdjEstCostPrice").Value,
        CostPrice = x.Element(ns + "CostPrice").Value,
        VehicleCode = x.Element(ns + "VehicleCode").Value,
        //etc
    });
```

Comment: I did update my attempt with namespaces..mentioned above, but still nada.
eg. var r = xml
     .Descendants("{" + ns + "}VehicleValue").Elements()
     .Select(x => new
     {
      #region all the Nodes/Fields

      AdjustedEstimatedCostPrice = x.Element("{" + ns + "}AdjustedEstimatedCostPrice").Value

Comment: Yes, that code is wrong. Try the code I just posted. It's not just about namespaces. Don't do the `.Elements()` call before the `Select()`

Comment: @David ..Just tried your suggestion, ..unfortunately nada

Comment: Well, it does work, I can assure you. In fact, here is proof: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8d3iun

Comment: @NealRogers - but this is the correct approach, I think you should double (and triple) check your code and data. And then again. Your posting here was sloppy and full of errors, you'll have to correct any errors that DavidG copied.

Comment: Indeed, I already had to fix the XML by adding a missing `"` and removing those pesky `-` characters.

Comment: I cut and pasted it from the XML visualizer (apologies)

Comment: @NealRogers OK, but can you see the example I show that works?

Comment: @DavidG ...Yup,  that works.
I mistakenly believed that it would write the values to Properties I had already set up,..not thinking that the "Field names" in the select where local or incorporated into the result var.
Thanks

Comment: @NealRogers The best programming advice I can give you is: "always be pedantic". You'll find more bugs and write much better code if you are fastidious like that.